# Best strategy for dealing with optional dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm currently in the process of removing the Spring dependency from [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org). In the future though other types of dependencies might be needed to support a subset of users (such as JBoss VFS support).

Which is the **best way to support optional dependencies** (optional=true in Maven POM)?

Qualities of the solution would be:

- Ease of use for end-users (minimum work required to use functionality if dependency is present)
- Ease of use for developers (code dealing with optional dependency should be as readable and as straightforward as possible)
- No unnecessary required dependencies (if some end-user don't need this functionality, no need to pull in the dependency)

Comment: **Update:** just to clarify, the things I am unsure about are
 - POM design
 - reflection vs multiple modules vs both vs ...
 - autodiscovery or not of additional modules if they are present/if yes, how
 - ...

Comment: Update: I've finally come around to writing a comprehensive blog post about this: http://www.axelfontaine.com/2012/08/optional-dependency-strategies-for-java.html

Answer (score 12):

I think Maven's optional dependency functionality is quite limited.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Optional dependencies will not get pulled down (as transitive dependencies) by default. However, if your users need to use these optional features the missing dependencies must be explicitly declared, in their POM.

Personally, it's not clear to me how this is helpful to users.... I suppose the optional dependencies in your POM do document which versions your code depends on. Not all users however will read the POM, all they'll see is the "NoClassDef Found" error :-(

My final observation is that this is one of those rare scenarios where a dependency manager like [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) offers more flexibility. Ivy has a concept called "configurations". Module authors can assemble different combinations of dependencies, for example "with-spring" or "without-spring".

Comment: Good point about the pom & the dependency versions. What about the code side of things? How to divide up modules/avoid NoClassDefFound/etc? Please expand.

Comment: @martiell has given an excellent outline of the kinds of sub-optimal work-arounds available to you.... I really don't think there is a good way to do this in Maven. Deploying multiple Maven modules, each with their own custom POM would seem to be the best and simpliest option for your users (but more work for you).

Comment: Dagger 2 has a good use of <optional>.  The annotation compiler uses this to be available during compilation but not when this module is used by other artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

There's a choice of:

- keep the project in a single module; and use optional dependencies.
- split the project into multiple modules; where each module has a (non-optional) dependency on any libraries;

I think the first makes more sense in most cases: users need to figure out their way around fewer artifacts. Typically, they'll have to add fewer new dependencies to their pom. Unless the code to support third-party projects is large, this will help improve maven download times too (fewer round-trips).  With the latter approach, you can find yourself in awkward situations where the user has defined their own set of versions, but only for some of the third-party dependencies.

I prefer to see the optional dependencies in the pom (I sometimes look to see which version it's built against). It's true that some people might not look. I think copy-and-pasteable pom snippets on the website is the best solution for that. For example, if you have a page about Spring integration, you could put the relevant pom snippet on that page.

I'd suggest that non-free dependencies (or anything not easily resolvable) be kept in a separate maven module, so that contributors are always able to build the primary artifact. (I had that problem with Quartz, which IIRC has an optional dependency on an Oracle JDBC jar).

Edit: If you're worried about users seeing NoClassDefFoundErrors, it wouldn't do any harm to check that the class can be resolved before trying to use it. For example, you could can an exception, and throw a more meaningful error message pointing the user to documentation. SLF4J is a good example of this.