# Making a requiring an explicit maven dependency on a transitive dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-plugin

I am creating a maven plugin that itself has a dependency DEP.  DEP can be one of several versions.  What I need is that consumers must explicitly mention DEP and its version.  I don't want consumers to use an implicit dependency on DEP and automatically get new versions when I release new DEPs.

Here is what I have now, but this means that if DEP is not specified in the consumer's pom, then they will always get the latest one.

In my plugin's dependency section, I have this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>DEP</artifactId>
        <version>[1.8.3-01,9.9.9)</version>
    </dependency> 
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Then, someone using my plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>my-compiler-id/compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>my-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the case above, everything works for the consumer and they *always* get the latest version of `DEP`.  If they want a specific version of `DEP, then they need to explicitly add it in their pom, like so in the dependencies section of the maven-compiler-plugin:

```
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>DEP</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.6-09</version>
                </dependency>
```

Now, this extra explicit dependency is *optional*.  If missing, the latest is used.  I want to make this dependency *mandatory*. How do I do that?

Comment: You want to make it mandatory that the user of your plugin define the `DEP` and a specific version, rather than just defaulting to latest?

Comment: Do you want the build to fail?

Comment: Yes. Build should fail if dependency is not explicit from consumer.  Ideally, would be nice if a meaningful error could come out: "Missing DEP dependency. Please add it...", but that is not a requirement.

Comment: Have you just tried declaring DEP as `<optional>` in your plugin pom?

Comment: Hadn't thought of that.  It might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define your DEP as an "optional" dependency, as described in the following question and linked blog post:

[Best strategy for dealing with optional dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967390/best-strategy-for-dealing-with-optional-dependencies)

http://axelfontaine.com/blog/optional-dependencies.html

Essentially just:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
                <artifactId>DEP</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.6-09</version>
                <optiona>true</optional>
            </dependency>
```

Now your users will have to explicitly add this dependency when using this plugin, otherwise, they will encounter errors.

There might also be some way to accomplish the same result but with more informative error messages - using [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) or [writing a custom plugin](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins.html) that wraps/extends the compiler plugin, but `<optional>` is probably the most expedient approach.

Comment: Thanks.  Working very nicely now.  I am able to construct the my-compiler-id class so that it first checks to see if DEP is around before it tries to load anything from it.  And I catch the ClassNotFoundError and print out a readable error message telling the user exactly what to do.